# NHibernate running unnecessary UPDATE command after INSERT - Unidirectional Many-To-One relationship

Tags: oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate

I have a uniderational many-to-one relationship from **Claim** to **Brand**. (One claim has one brand associated with it).

Following is the mapping, which works fine -

**Claim.hbm.xml**:

```
<many-to-one name="Brand" class="Brand" column="BRAND_CODE" />
```

However, when I save a claim, like this -

```
var c = new Claim();
//Assign other properties to claim.
session.Get<Brand>(brandId);
c.Brand = brand;
session.SaveOrUpdate(c);
```

After an insert command in the `CLAIM` table, nhibernate also runs an unnecessary update command on the `BRAND` table. Although this may not be an issue in most cases, I am working with a legacy database that has triggers on update of the `BRAND` table. I do not want these triggers to run.

From NHibernate's Log:

```
INSERT INTO JLL$SECSALES.SEC_STOCKIST_CLAIM_DET (ACTIVITY_CODE, COMP_CODE, COST_LEVEL1, COST_LEVEL2, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE, CLAIM_AMT, APPROVED_AMT, CLAIM_STATUS, REMARKS, VARIANCE, ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID, STOCKIST_CLAIM_ID_DET_ID, STOCKIST_CLAIM_ID) VALUES (:p0, :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9, :p10, :p11, :p12, :p13);:p0 = 'ACT123' [Type: String (6)], :p1 = 'ACCDEP' [Type: String (6)], :p2 = 'DIV0000006' [Type: String (10)], :p3 = 'ABLE CHERIYAN K C ( E000005577 )' [Type: String (32)], :p4 = 01/28/2014 12:00:00 AM [Type: DateTime (0)], :p5 = 01/28/2014 12:00:00 AM [Type: DateTime (0)], :p6 = 0 [Type: Single (0)], :p7 = 0 [Type: Single (0)], :p8 = 'N' [Type: StringFixedLength (1)], :p9 = 'AAA' [Type: String (3)], :p10 = 0 [Type: Single (0)], :p11 = NULL [Type: Int64 (0)], :p12 = 1 [Type: Int64 (0)], :p13 = 12 [Type: Int64 (0)]
UPDATE JLL$TRAN.BRAND_MAST SET BRAND_DESC = :p0, REC_STATUS = :p1, ADDDATE = :p2, MODDATE = :p3, AUTHDATE = :p4, ADDUSER = :p5, MODUSER = :p6, AUTHUSER = :p7 WHERE BRAND_CODE = :p8;:p0 = 'BOXER' [Type: String (5)], :p1 = 'A' [Type: StringFixedLength (1)], :p2 = 12/28/2009 1:41:38 PM [Type: DateTime (0)], :p3 = 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM [Type: DateTime (0)], :p4 = 12/28/2009 1:41:41 PM [Type: DateTime (0)], :p5 = 'PRADOSH' [Type: String (7)], :p6 = NULL [Type: String (0)], :p7 = 'PRADOSH' [Type: String (7)], :p8 = 'BND0000022' [Type: String (10)]
```

I have tried `insert="false"`, `update="false"`, `cascade="none"` on the many-to-one relationship, but in vain. How can I prevent the unnecessary update statement?

Comment: In usual scenarios this will never happen. The most suspected here is the wrong mapping of the Brand. For example: 1) some of the Brand properties is mapped as `not-null="true"` and in fact it is null or 2) there is some application trigger/aop updating the *UpdateDate* or *UpdatedBy* ... in any of these cases NHibernate will realize, that `brand` loaded as `session.Get<Brand>(id)` is dirty... and will issue the UPDATE during the `Flush()`. Other words: it is not related to the mapping mentioned above... I would say

Comment: `Brand` is a model which our application will never change. It is just used in `many-to-one` relationships with multiple tables. I just removed the mapping of all the unnecessary columns of the `brand` table from the Brand model, and it worked. I did not understand why, but it worked!

Comment: The point is, that NHibernate and its `ISession` are working a bit differently, then one would expect. Once anyhting is loaded into session, it is evaluated if it is *pristine* or *dirty*. If any property (really any;) is changed, and the instance is marked as dirty... the `Flush()` phase will put it on the stack of items to be updated. Anyhow, great to see that you did it! Enjoy NHibernate. Amazing tool ;)

Comment: On an unrelated note you should use session.Load instead of get to set proxy objects to avoid unnecessary lookups.  `c.Brand = session.Load<Brand>(brandId)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Brand is a model which our application will never change. It is just used in many-to-one relationships with multiple tables. I just removed the mapping of all the unnecessary columns of the brand table from the Brand model, and it worked. I did not understand why, but it worked!

I ran into an issue similar to this where there was a one-to-many relationship between two entities.  I had the collection end marked with Inverse().  Whenever I inserted a new child entity, NHibernate would immediately issue an update for the parent entity.  This update was then blowing up because of an integrity issue on one of the fields.

I took a close look at the SQL and the table and came to the realization that there were a significant number of fields with numeric values that were marked as nullable in the table, but not in the class to which the table was mapped.  The issue was that NHibernate was dutifully converting the nulls to zeroes.  Because the field actually had a value now where before it was null, it marked those fields as dirty and justifiably attempted an update of the record in the database.  The solution was to go back to the class and mark the numeric properties as nullable.  Once I completed this task, I recompiled and no more update after the insert.

The fact that the removal of your fields caused the insert to "go away" indicates that there was something wrong with those fields and may have been something similar to what I experienced.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the inverse attribute of the bag or set element in the NH mapping.

http://blog.lowendahl.net/data-access/managing-parentchild-relationships-with-nhibernate-inverse-management/

Comment: But there is no bag at the other end of the relationship. It is a uni-directional relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Enable dynamic updates on the class so that only the changed properties are updated. This will tell you which properties NHibernate has detected as dirty and should allow you to troubleshoot why the property is changing after the save.

```
<class ... dynamic-update="true">
```